Accessing Main-Actor isolated properties from a nonisolated, synchronous context?
I'm trying to migrate the code of an old github project to Swift6 language and I'm facing the following issue:
I have a nonisolated, non mainactor class that uses a MPVolumeView, whose initialiser is main actor isolated. This means that the following code results in an error in Swift 6:
internal final class MyClass: Sendable {
    private let volumeView: MPVolumeView = .init(frame: zero)
}

So in an attempt to fix, I mark this property as @MainActor:
internal final class MyClass: Sendable {
    @MainActor private let volumeView: MPVolumeView = .init(frame: zero)
}

This solves the warning but forces main-actor isolation whenever I need to access volumeView or any of its property.
Now say that I want to forward volumeView properties:
internal final class MyClass: Sendable {
    @MainActor private let volumeView: MPVolumeView = .init(frame: zero)

    internal var isAirPlayConnected: Bool {
        get async {
            let result = await self.volumeView.isWirelessRouteActive
            return result
        }
    }
}

This way I can forward the volumeView.isWirelessRouteActive without forcing main-actor isolation (which I don't want to).
Assume that I need to access this property whose getter is marked as async from a synchronous context that I can't change to be asynchronous in any way. For example inside a deinit { } block or inside a delegate method (for example UIScrollViewDelegate or UIPageViewControllerDelegate).
What I tried was the following:
let taskLock = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
Task { @MainActor in
    await someAsyncMethodThatUsesAsyncGetter()
    taskLock.signal()
}
        
taskLock.wait()

The unfortunate occurrence with this method is that when called from the main thread (that is my use case), it results in a deadlock, since the thread waits for a signal that should come from another task running on the same thread.
So what's the correct way to handle this kind of situation when migrating code from Swift 5 to Swift 6?

"So what's the correct way to handle this kind of situation when migrating code from Swift 5 to Swift 6?" Redesign to not require that. Swift 6 specifically does not allow "access this property whose getter is marked as async from a synchronous context that I can't change to be asynchronous in any way." Every attempt to work around that will be a hack with various dangers. IMO, this is a serious flaw in Swift 6 that impacts our ability to deploy it, but it is how Swift 6 works. There is no "correct way" to this question.

@RobNapier: So assume I don't necessarily want to make the getter async. How do I give an initial value to the property with a default value initialiser that's MainActor isolated? Without making the whole init MainActor isolated because it might be quite expensive?
One day compilers will drop support for Swift 4/5 and it makes no sense that there's not a way to port old code to the new version of Swift, otherwise it wouldn't be called Swift anymore I guess?

To be honest, the whole of MyClass should be main actor-isolated since it handles UIViews. If you have something that you really want to run off of the main actor, make those things nonisolated. What do you mean by "it might be quite expensive"?

@Sweeper: As far as my mind serves it doesn't handle UIViews in the sense that the MPVolumeView isn't added as a subview anywhere. It is just used to gain access to informations such as availability of AirPlay or stuff like that.

"added as a subview" isn't the criteria. It operates heavily on a UIView. Nothing about a UIView is allowed to be accessed on other threads. That would encourage you to make the entire class MainActor, or provide a wrapper that is MainActor and provides nonisolated "last snapshot" values. Or use an AsyncChannel to pass values across isolation contexts. All the answers for "how should nonisolated types talk to directly to MainActor types" are currently janky. The general answer is "do it as little as possible."

To the question of how to port old code; the answer in many cases is turning out to be "heavily redesign it." Yes, that's kind of a mess. But there aren't always low-impact ways to convert things that relied on "I know I won't access something on the wrong thread" into "the compiler can prove it can't happen." Swift 6 does not always have a mechanical (or even available-today) conversion available to all Swift 5 code. There is an old Cocoa tradition of "put it all on the main thread." That continues, even though Swift 6 isn't really built for that.

@RobNapier: Sometimes I feel it's literally impossible to achieve some of the previous Swift versions' functionalities. For example I can't guarantee that the NotificationCenter.default.addObserver callback labelled as using is executed with MainActor isolation but I need to observe notifications with no workaround I can think of.

Yeah, isolating the whole class to the main actor is going to be much easier than isolating individual properties. Step back and ask yourself what thread the original implementation was using throughout: There’s a good chance that is was running everything on the main thread, and if so, isolating the whole thing to the main actor is going to be the easiest solution.

Re NotificationCenter, if it was using the .main queue, you can wrap the code inside that closure in a MainActor.assumeIsolated {…}. This is a macOS example, but the idea is the same in iOS. Or alternatively, you can retire addObserver in favor of the notifications asynchronous sequence, as contemplated here.

@Rob: this way I basically can’t use addObserver anymore because it’s non isolated and I need to update instance members inside it

That’s the point of wrapping the code inside the closure with MainActor.assumeIsolated {…} (assuming using was .main). It says, “hey, if you’re on the main thread already, go ahead and isolate everything in this closure to the main actor,” thereby allowing you to update those main-actor-isolated properties. It transforms that non-isolated closure context to one that is isolated to the main actor.

By the way, setting aside the deadlock issue, you cannot use locks as contemplated in your question. It is expressly forbidden to use a lock across asynchronous contexts.

@Rob: I kinda guessed that, as you get compilation error when calling wait() from an async context

assumeIsolated is a powerful tool that you definitely want to know about. If your issue is "I know for absolute certain that this is on the main actor, but the compiler can't prove it," then assumeIsolated lets you prove it. Just note that it crashes if not on the main actor. "I don't want to crash!" so many cry out when they learn this. So…were you really certain that it was always on the main actor? Swift 6  forces us to be certain of things we used to just say "I'm pretty sure" about.

“I'm trying to migrate the code of an old github project” … Is this a public github repo? If so, can you share a link to it? We can probably offer better counsel with a more complete example of what you are trying to migrate to Swift 6.

Also, you said “I can forward x without forcing main-actor isolation (which I don't want to).” … Why don’t you? Did the old class really do a lot on a background thread? There is nothing in the provided code snippets to suggest that was the case. Hey, if you want to refine it to move more code to a thread from the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool, tackle that later, but don’t get lost in that during this initial migration to Swift 6.

FWIW, WWDC 2021 video Swift concurrency: Update a sample app is a great, practical example of migrating to Swift concurrency. And 2024’s Migrate your app to Swift 6 helps wrap your head around some of the Swift 6 specific issues.
